# What percentage of PhD theses are rejected nowadays?

Tags: phd, thesis, science

What percentage of PhD theses (e.g., physics ones) are rejected nowadays? And why?

Comment: Probably varies widely by department, location, etc. You shouldn't *have* to narrow it down, but might you want to?

Comment: @NickStauner: What do you mean I "shouldn't *have* to narrow it down"? I just want to know general trends. E.g., are fewer being rejected now than, say, 50 or 100 years ago?

Comment: Not sure what was unclear, but I'll try paraphrasing. Since that's your intent, you shouldn't (be required to?) narrow it down (even though doing so might make the question easier to answer).

Comment: What do you mean by "rejected"?  For example, that a thesis defense takes place but the student fails and leaves graduate school without a Ph.D.?  What if the student fails but is told to try again later after doing a little more work?  What about a student who thinks he/she should graduate but whose thesis committee disagrees and won't schedule a defense?  You might be able to find statistics for failed defenses, but by itself that data may not tell you much.  (My impression is that most borderline theses never make it to the defense.)

Comment: At many universities (my experience is exclusively EU-centric) there are at least two self-censorship filters before it comes to a defense. Firstly, and most importantly, it's the thesis supervisor who must approve your manuscript as defensible. Secondly, you  often also need a dean's approval for moving on towards  an actual defense. There are many theses which do not make it through these safeguard filters on their first attempt, but if the system works, you almost never see an officially failed defense/rejected thesis. Hence the numbers on the actual "failure rate" do not really exist.

Comment: @walkmanyi Same for Austria and Switzerland. I have never heard of somebody 'failing' their defense (that would be an affront against the advisor just as much as against the student), but certainly there are people that just never finish their PhD. I would say, in my group drop-out rate was around 25% - 33%, but I never bothered to count.

Comment: @xLeitix: Interesting, I just checked the regulations of doctorates for EPFL and ETHZ and they do not seem to stipulate an approval of a supervisor before submitting a thesis. So in principal you could be able to submit crap, though that does not seem to happen in practice.

Comment: At Ohio State, everyone on your committee must sign a form approving a draft of the dissertation before the defense can be scheduled. http://www.gradsch.osu.edu/7.10-final-oral-exam.html

Comment: @AnonymousMathematician: I mean the thesis or its defense is not accepted, such that the PhD student has to write a new thesis, perhaps in another department, and re-defend it.

Comment: @walkmanyi in Sweden, a board reviews it before the defence, and can recommend you to improve it. You are allowed to ignore them, at your own risk (and there was recently a case where this happened).

Comment: There is another very interesting question about the variance of quality of theses that do pass.  As there is almost no visibility surrounding which theses are passed (unlike, say, exam questions in an undergraduate degree) I suspect that it is dramatically high, even if you exclude the top 1% say.

Comment: In some graduate schools (e.g. the one I'm confronted with at Harvard), one factor is the 'qualifying exam'. I know of someone with a good publication record, whose adviser think she/he perfectly qualifies for the PhD, and who failed her/his qualifying exam. No PhD for that person, although the quality of the work far exceeds the one of the average thesis I have seen in the field.

Comment: @walkmanyi from my experience at EPFL, there is usually the 'private defense', a from of closed-doors exam with your thesis committee, then only if the committee agrees can the student officially defend.

Comment: I talked to my own supervisor about this, and it became clear that one of the main roles of the supervisor is to ensure that the thesis is good enough before it is submitted. And speaking for myself, I would never submit a thesis if my supervisor told me it was not defendable. But this means it could be that I will end up not being able to submit my thesis at all, because my supervisor thinks my thesis is not ready to be submitted. So I think maybe a more relevant question would be "how many PhD students never submit their thesis because their supervisor thinks the thesis is not good enough".

Comment: Here, for undergraduate theses in some 25 years, I remember one student who failed the defense.

Comment: @walkmanyi: "they do not seem to stipulate an approval of a supervisor before submitting a thesis" - possible, but I think the vast majority of doctoral candidates are experienced enough to adhere to the *non-binding advice* of their supervisors without being required to do so.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm only personally aware of one student who failed his PhD defense (this is at an R1 US university). After his advisor refused to approve his thesis, he went over his head and got the department chair to schedule the defense anyway. Results were predictable.

On the other hand, "major revisions" are very common, especially, I hear, in the humanities (in engineering, it's far more common to receive token feedback -- if the committee reads the thesis at all! -- than demands for substantial changes).

Outright failing a student during a defense is an extreme embarassment, for the department, for the PhD committee, for the advisor, and of course for the student, so there is every incentive to ensure that a thesis that goes to defense will pass. Moreover, since most theses these days are compilations of previously-published work, it is very easy to tell well in advance if the student is expected to pass.

So if an advisor has doubts about the quality of a student's thesis, he will either ask the student to spend more time improving it, or "suggest" the student start looking for jobs in industry.

Answer (score 20):

Very small, as every failed PhD defence is also a shame for the professor. As a result, the professor will not allow to proceed with defence of the really weak work. And he will listen for other professors that would usually tell in advance they think to vote against.

Hence, most likely, the following will happen:

- If a PhD student just does not work enough, the professor
  will not allow to continue studies after some time.
- If a PhD
  student is mad with some own theory or topic that academic community
  unlikely to accept, the professor will not allow to defend such a
  work.
- If it is really a bad luck with your topic, the professor will
  change the topic.
- If the professor has made a strategic mistake and
  your diligent work does not give results that could be published in a
  good journal, the professor should normally try to publish anyway in less reputable sources, good enough for PhD defence.

The PhD supervisor is more interested in your success than a lecturer is interested in the progress of the student. Same professor that writes low grades with relatively little attention (as long as he is sure the student deserves) will spend more time when acting as a PhD supervisor, will try to help, will try to fix the topic. This is because PhD project is also *his* research project. And who would want ones research project to fail? Of course, the professor tries to find a good PhD student for his project, or, if this was not successful, at least to fire lazy or uncooperative student in the first year. But this is way before the actual PhD defence.

If to ask differently, how many PhD students do not get they degree at the end, this really depends a lot on the traditions inside the institution. However in all places I have seen this was below 20 % or about. The first post doctoral position is also seldom a problem.

The next serious threshold you will need to pass is the professor position or at least a permanent researcher position, if you want to stay in science.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a university that requires the advisor to approve the thesis before being submitted. In my experience this is not how it works in the US or UK.

Comment: Regardless of the rules, it is very uncommon to go to defence against the will of the supervisor, and you really cannot expect to pass if you are in such a conflict, at least in European system. I have seen cases in Germany, Switzerland and Lithuania.

Comment: But the rules really only come into effect for the students who might not get approval. To the extent that the UK is part of the European system, the supervisor has no say in if a student passes or not. I think this is also the case in the Australian system.

Comment: To say differently, if the supervisor thinks you will pass, you will most likely pass. And, with the help of your supervisor, it should not be extremely difficult to bring your PhD into good shape. The PhD supervisor is more interested in your success than a lecturer is interested in the progress of the student. But if you are in a conflict instead, chances to succeed are minor. For such a case, I would suggest to change the supervisor instead, even if this would mean changing the university as well.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub: just a quick example of a university requiring an approval of a thesis supervisor before engaging a panel of examiners/reviewers: TU Delft. See article 18.2 (pg. 24), as well as the formal process description (row 6 in table pg. 8) in the [TU Delft doctorate regulations](https://intranet.tudelft.nl/fileadmin/UD/MenC/Support/Internet/TU%20Website/TU%20Delft/Homepage_TU_Delft/Documenten/Onderzoek/Promoveren/Promotiezaken/Doctorate_Regulations_TUDelft_ENG_2011_09.pdf).

Comment: I know the second point you made, @h22 all too good. This is why I failed my PhD-it wasn't because I lacked ideas or was incompetent student, simply the professor didn't even had experience in the area I was going in. There weren't enough money then, too, so instead of receiving funding (for a project which was really **unique** at the academic background I was in then) I was left with the choice to either participate in what **he** wanted me to do or leave. This is how most of the drop-outs happen as far as I know. Those who oblige to their peers ***always*** get through no matter what their

Comment: work accounts to. You have to be very (really *very*) sloppy to get rejected if you just do what "the elders say". This is why there is almost 100% success rate for those who "listen up" and they almost all the time graduate. **However**, the fact that you don't "listen up" doesn't may your work meaningless! It's just that sometimes the professors are too **narrow-minded** to participate in the pursuit of ideas they themselves can't fully comprehend. But I guess you can be a scientist even without a PhD if the work you've done gets accepted some day.

Comment: In short. Trust your supervisors. If you have a good relationship with them (or even a bad one honestly), and they think you will pass, then you will almost certainly pass.

If: you go over your supervisors head, your supervisors have been sub-par or not supportive, your supervisors have not thoroughly read your thesis, then you have more cause for concern.